# Change default popup.html in options.html (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension, with 2 different versions (a new and a old) so people that are used to the old look can keep it.
I know what the JS to change the default popup is `chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: 'new/index.html' })`, but no-matter what I try, I cant get options.html to change it.

Currently my options.js is this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var New = document.getElementById('NewBtn');
New.addEventListener('click', function() {
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: 'new/index.html' });
});
```

The console has a error, that says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (options.js:3)
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="options.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="NewBtn" >New</button>
</html>
```

Anyone know what I should do?
Thanks in advance, -Fred

Comment: The error message says there's no element with `id="NewBtn"` in your html file.

Comment: My html has a button with this html:
<button id="NewBtn" >New</button>

Comment: there, I shared the html file @wOxxOm

Comment: You don't have a closing `</body>` tag and missing another `})` in the script. I see an error in devtools: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input". The popup is a separate page with its own devtools window which you can invoke by right-clicking inside the popup, then clicking "inspect".

Comment: Thank you so much @wOxxOm that worked!